# FTP with curlftpfs is extremely slow to the point it is impossible to work with

Tags: ftp, curlftpfs

I mounted ftp location by using curlftpfs . The problem is that it is EXTREMELY slow to the point it is useless. The time of performing pretty much everything is about 10 seconds. It even includes getting any VIM command to work, including navigation (!) . I started to think that maybe I'm doing something wrong as it is impossible to work at all with that responsiveness. It would be a lot faster to download->edit->upload files with FileZilla if I need to wait 10s for moving cursor down one line in vim. Anyone have any idea why it could be that? Is it possible to make it faster with some curlftpfs options?

I have pretty good connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the reason for extreme slowness of vim was powerline plugin. curlftpfs is still slow but I guess it is because FTP is what it is...

Answer (score 7):

Like said, it is slow because of `libcurl3-gnutls`, downgrading that is the current workaround but the consequences for the other dependencies (there are like 10-15 on my Xubuntu 14.04 system) are pretty much unknown.

I personally decided against downgrading but switched to `sshfs` for now. So if you have SSH access to your server this may work for you too. It is much faster than the currently broken `curlftpfs`. Here is a guide:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/how-to-mount-a-remote-folder-using-ssh-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 4):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/curlftpfs/+bug/1267749?comments=all
http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=176334&pid=1591001#pid1591001

A few people have determined that `libcurl3-gnutls` is the culprit, and that downgrading helps. I'm not a fan of this, because many packages rely on an up to date `libcurl3-gnutls`. So, I also deal with the slowness, but am not sure what a good answer is.

Answer (score 0):

Although this thread is pretty old, I faced the same problem. I found out that adding the option `direct_io` speeds up the download rate dramatically. What I understood is that `direct_io` switches off some cache. No idea why this is needed or slows down the process.