# Changing one particular shared library in executable binary

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, reverse-engineering, elf

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360479/ftp-with-curlftpfs-is-extremely-slow-to-the-point-it-is-impossible-to-work-with) is written that `curlftpfs` is terribly slow because of bug in newest `libcurl3-gnutls`. Downgrading is not recommended due to large reverse dependencies that this package has (can be verified via `apt-cache showpkg libcurl3-gnutls:amd64` or `apt-cache rdepends libcurl3-gnutls:amd64`). So I've decided to downgrade it different way. I've checked available versions in repository:

```
$ apt-cache policy libcurl3-gnutls:amd64
libcurl3-gnutls:
  Installed: 7.43.0-1ubuntu2.1
  Candidate: 7.43.0-1ubuntu2.1
  Version table:
 *** 7.43.0-1ubuntu2.1 0
        500 http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.43.0-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
```

Then I've downloaded and extracted older version than installed one:

```
$ apt-get install -d libcurl3-gnutls=7.43.0-1ubuntu2
$ sudo mv /var/cache/apt/archives/libcurl3-gnutls_7.43.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb .
$ dpkg -x libcurl3-gnutls_7.43.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb  extracted_deb
```

Then I've backed up original binary and searched for some common name in shared libraries:

```
$ cp $(which curlftpfs) .
$ ldd ./curlftpfs | grep curl
        libcurl-gnutls.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4 (0x00007fcac4443000)

$ readelf -d ./curlftpfs  | grep -i curl
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcurl-gnutls.so.4]
```

Following step was just the proof that linked file belongs exactly to `libcurl3-gnutls` package and that `curlftpfs` depends on `libcurl3-gnutls`:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4
libcurl3-gnutls:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4

$ apt-cache depends curlftpfs
curlftpfs
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libcurl3-gnutls
  Depends: libfuse2
  Depends: libglib2.0-0
  Depends: fuse
  Conflicts: curlftpfs:i386
```

Also the content of extracted and installed `libcurl3-gnutls` package seems exactly the same:

```
$ dpkg -L libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 | sort
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.3.0
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libcurl3-gnutls
/usr/share/doc/libcurl3-gnutls/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libcurl3-gnutls/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libcurl3-gnutls/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libcurl3-gnutls

$ find extracted_deb/ | sort
extracted/
extracted/usr
extracted/usr/lib
extracted/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
extracted/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.3
extracted/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4
extracted/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.3.0
extracted/usr/share
extracted/usr/share/doc
extracted/usr/share/doc/libcurl3-gnutls
extracted/usr/share/doc/libcurl3-gnutls/changelog.Debian.gz
extracted/usr/share/doc/libcurl3-gnutls/copyright
extracted/usr/share/doc/libcurl3-gnutls/NEWS.Debian.gz
extracted/usr/share/lintian
extracted/usr/share/lintian/overrides
extracted/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libcurl3-gnutls
```

My question is how can I rewrite the path that is contained in `ldd` output and point it to file that I've extracted? I've read about `rpath` and `patchelf` and `chrpath` [here](https://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/notes/rpath.html) and [here](https://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/notes/rpath.html) but I guess this is not my case because following commands returns nothing useful:

```
$ readelf -d ./curlftpfs | grep -i rpath
$
$ chrpath -l ./curlftpfs
./curlftpfs: no rpath or runpath tag found.
$
$ patchelf --print-rpath ./curlftpfs
$
```

So it seems that `rpath` is not used. I've also read about `$LD_LIBRARY_PRELOAD` but I guess that it will change path for all shared libraries for given binary not just one particular (in my case `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4`) so I would need to have whole tree of libraries. [There](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24811/changing-linked-library-for-a-given-executable-centos-6) is also solutions which suggest changing loader (in my example `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` I guess):

```
$ patchelf --print-interpreter ./curlftpfs 
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
$
$ ldd ./curlftpfs | grep ld-linux
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000564966b64000)
$
$ ls -laL /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.21.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 154376 Mar 26  2015 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.21.so
```

but to be honest I didn't get the point of this. Can you please assists?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how can I rewrite the path that is contained in ldd
>   output and point it to file that I've extracted?

It seems like what you want is to override the functionality for just the libcurl-gnutls.so library with an older version. As hinted to in the last link you provided, you can use the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable to override the standard library functions.

Say your manually installed (downgraded) version of libcurl-gnutls has the dynamic library file /usr/local/lib/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.4.0.
You could then do something like the following:
`LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.4.0 curlftpfs [some_arguments...]`

Don't forget that /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4 and /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.3 are just symbolic links to the master library file for libcurl-gnutls. Copying these symbolic links may not have the desired effect. You need the long named SO file, like libcurl-gnutls.so.4.4.0 .

#### Extra Notes

You can test that this override worked by doing something like the following:
`LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.4.0 ldd $(which curlftpfs)`

For a manual installation, /usr/local/lib may not be a good place to put a dynamic library that you don't want interfering with other binaries. This is because /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf may point to /usr/local/lib for automatic libraries. (My Debian machine does)

To see the definitions of the LD_ environment variable, check out the [ld.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) man page (`man ld.so`).

Comment: Thank you for reply. One question is this changing one particular library? In this case `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4`. Would be also possible to somehow modify binary to point to this library? Thank you.

Comment: This would effectively be changing this one particular library, since it will override all/primary functions provided by the original library. In this case it would override `libcurl-gnutls.so.4`, if curlftpfs was compiled to use that library.
I suspect there should be a clever way to rewrite a binary's linking information to use a different shared library name, but I currently do not posses that knowledge. As a manual hack, you could try using a hex editor and change the text that specifies `libcurl-gnutls.so.4` to maybe `libcurl-gnutls.so.2` (probably should be same length name).

Comment: Honestly, if you are thinking about modifying the `curlftpfs` binary, you should probably just compile `curlftpfs` by hand and change the dependencies.

Comment: Of course I can but I was mainly interested in some reverse engineering approach

Comment: Alright, then, as previously mentioned, you can rename the library dependency inside the binary using a hex editor like Bless. I just tried it with the `ls` binary. Just open the hex editor on the `curlftpfs` binary. Search for `libcurl-gnutls.so.4` text. Rename the file inline, while maintaining the original length. If you need more detail, I can write another answer.